# Pages wont load if it has session_start(); in it

Tags: php, apache, session, xampp

I've recently switched from years of WAMP to XAMPP because I wanted PHP 7, but I've noticed something I've never experienced before, it wont load php files that have `session_start();` in them. I just get "Waiting for localhost..." in Chrome/IE/FF. As soon as I remove that line the page loads.

Worked fine in wamp.

Basically every page that contains `session_start();` wont load, super weird. But if I remove it, they load and show.

Why?

error log just notices

```
[Sun Dec 27 02:52:19.346602 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3272:tid 372] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 27 02:52:19.346602 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3272:tid 372] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39
[Sun Dec 27 02:52:19.346602 2015] [core:notice] [pid 3272:tid 372] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Sun Dec 27 02:52:19.348604 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3272:tid 372] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2744
[Sun Dec 27 02:52:19.607869 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2744:tid 380] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Dec 27 02:52:19.674491 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2744:tid 380] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Dec 27 02:52:19.699518 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2744:tid 380] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

EDIT: just found this, I have the **exact** same problem. he never found a solution

[session_start() keeps the file load forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273567/session-start-keeps-the-file-load-forever)

EDIT2: I went back to WAMP and installed php7 myself

Comment: Could we please take a look at your code?

Comment: dont matter, even an file with only session_start() keeps loading forever. check my edit

Comment: Is your browser accepting cookies? Have you tried connecting to `127.0.0.1` instead? Have you tried setting up `init_set()` to display errors?

Comment: @ConsiderMe, Yes, yes and yes, I get no errors, which probably is because the page wont load as soon as it sees "session_start()". probably going back to wamp today

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem, with the error `[Sun Dec 27 20:48:24.481770 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1188:tid 488] AH00428: Parent: child process 672 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.` as well.

Answer (score 5):

Find in php.ini:

```
session.use_only_cookies=0
```

change to:

```
session.use_only_cookies=1
```

I had the same trouble with the latest XAMPP version 7.0.1 with php7.

According to Bitnami Developers via Apache Friends Support:

> The issue is related to the use_only_cookies variable that you can
> find in the Session's section of the php.ini file. Apache will crash
> if the use_only_cookies variable in the Session's section is set to 0
> and everything is fine if it's set to 1.
>
> We'll include those changes in the next version of XAMPP with PHP 7.
> We are building the installers with the version 7.0.2 and we'll
> release them as soon as possible.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've included this in my header.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

and that works fine with the latest version of XAMPP with the Apache and MySQL modules running.

Comment: I've tried making my index.php just <?php session_start(); ?>, my site wont load. No problem in wamp. I downloaded xampp an hour ago

Answer (score 1):

Run XAMPP as administrator. I just figured it out by going to this website:
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/solved-xampp-apache-error

Comment: I was facing exactly the same problem with php 7.0.1 on xampp v3.2.2, this solved the problem like magic. Thanks for this answer

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I just uninstall and install the 5.6.15 XAMPP version and the problem was solved, I thought that it was my Windows 8.1, but apparently there is a bug in 7.0.0